# Python. Включение точки доступа из приложения

Tags: android, python, linux, wifi

Как можно реализовать включение и выключение точки доступа из приложения?
Выполнением консольной команды из кода программы? Какие есть варианты?

Буду очень признателен за ссылки на эту тему.

Comment: В зависимости от модели и предоставленных точек входа. 22-й пор открыт?

Comment: @donRumata, а для чего 22 порт? Например приложение должно запуститься на ноутбуке и включить точку доступа с заданым именем и паролем.. не пойму заем порт 22 темболее..

Comment: зависит от ОС на которой будет запускаться точка доступа

Comment: А, так ты имеешь ввиду точку доступа на смарте средствами андройда? Я теги не посмотрел.

Comment: @donRumata создание и включение точки доступа я думаю как в линуксе так и в андроиде будет одинаковое за исключением нюансов, или я ошибаюсь? Вообще меня интересует на смарте и на ноуте с линуксом, инфы на эту тему вообще не нашел

Comment: @eri я думаю реализация на линуксе и на андроиде не сильно отличется, у вас есть какие нибудь ресурсы для изучения этого вопроса?

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров на андроиде нет доступа на это все

Comment: Да и с линуксом. На десктопном одно, на сервере другое, на роутере третье

Comment: Не, ты определись с платформой. А потом уже по ней задавай конкретные вопросы. Тут даже внутри андройда хренова гора вариантов. А то это напоминает "научите меня программировать".

Comment: @donRumata хорошо, возьмём андроид. Вы сказали много вариантов, посвятить меня в один из них? Я правильно понимаю что для всех требуется root?

Comment: Ни малейшего понятния. С андройдом не работаю. Знаю только, что помимо чистой версии от гугла - каждый производитель пилит свои надстройки. Плюс встречаются смарты с 4-й версией, потому что вроде бы мабила работает, но разраб забил на выкатывание обновлений. Так что ОЧЕНЬ многое зависит от реализации.